Core Loss of a Transformer
According to the Prof. Sam Ben-Yaakov, he uses the Core loss - \$P_v\$ (\$kW/m^3\$) versus  Flux Density - B (mT) graph which is provided by the core manufacturers datasheet to select the ΔB. The example of this graph is shown below:

Source : Samwha Ferrite Cores - Product Selection Guide 01
Then he uses the ΔB to calculate the \$A_p= A_w A_e\$, number of turns and so on. Everything is fine until now.
I have a core datasheet in which some of the core materials has this \$P_v - B\$ graph and some of them doesn't have. Thus I can not follow the way as Prof. Sam Ben-Yaakov.
The ones that doesn't have this \$P_v - B\$ graph has a table as shown below. According to the table below, I have 2 questions:

How can I know my core loss in order to follow the same way as above?

In order to know whether my core (or transformer) will saturate or not, I have 2 equation which are \$H= \frac {(N \times i)}{l}\$ and \$B = \frac {(μ_o \times μ_r \times N \times i)}{l}\$ . So by using this two formulas I can determine the B and check it from the table below which is given as saturation flux density. Am I thinking correct?



Source: Samwha Ferrite Cores - Product Selection Guide 01

First off, data-sheet information is part of the selection strategy for a component, beside cost and availability. If the information you need are not in the document, then choose another part. It is true for semiconductors but also for passive like caps or core material as in your case. Second, what is the application? The saturation phenomenon is not the same in a flyback or a forward converter for instance. For a flyback, it is like if you were designing an inductor: $NB_{sat}A_e>LI_p$ N is the number of turns, $A_e$ is the core area, $A_e$ the max flux density and max peak current.

Application is phase shift full bridge converter sir. How about core loss sir ? Is there a way to calculate it based on different applications ? There are some information about it in general but they are so complicated equations sir  @VerbalKint

@Rohat Kılıç your comments are valuable for me. Could you help about this topic ?

According to the table [above], you can't.
If I had to guess, given the high permeability of these types, they are intended for pulse transformer and EMI applications.  Pulse transformers aren't typically concerned with core loss, but with frequency range, impedance and insertion loss.  EMI filters aren't concerned with core loss (except perhaps in very large industrial applications), just impedance.  So, it's possible they don't publish loss curves because they aren't intended for power application.  They might also be published in another location and you just need to find them.
You could even assume that losses are typical among comparable ferrites, and look up cross-references or other similarities.  But this loses the design assurance of a proper datasheet for the material chosen.  Ferrites aren't that different, there isn't much variation between suppliers, or much development over the last some decades, the error is likely small (20%, say?) -- but you can't really know for sure without the exact datasheet.
Typically, power applications use low-ish permeability materials, in the 1000-3000 μr range, where losses are lower and cutoff frequency is a bit higher (fractional to few MHz where |μ| rolls off, instead of ~100kHz for μr ~ 10k).

if I calculate the max B based on my application, and then try to check it from the table above  whether it is exceeding or not , isn't this a suitable way sir ? @Tim Williams

Max B based on what? Saturation is one thing, core loss is another. Which is more important? I would assume given the PSFB that power levels are high, and core losses will matter.
